# Fail to open SSDP socket on Windows XP if already opened by other application

Tags: windows, sockets, udp, multicast

I want to listen to SSDP multicasts on port 1900. The port is already opened by Windows Discovery Service. I fail to bind my socket despite using SO_REUSEADDR socket option. I'm starting my application as administrator.

If I stop the service, start my application and then restart the service, then both get messages. What am I doing wrong?

```
static SOCKET CreateSocket(const char *ccAddress, unsigned short ulPort, struct IfPoolItem *item) {
struct sockaddr_in sAddr;
struct ip_mreq mc_req;
SOCKET sRet;
char cSockParam = TRUE;

/* create a socket */
if((sRet = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    return(INVALID_SOCKET);
}

item->s = sRet;

if (setsockopt(sRet, IPPROTO_IP, SO_REUSEADDR, &cSockParam, sizeof(cSockParam)) == -1) {
    int iTmp = WSAGetLastError();
    return (INVALID_SOCKET);
}

/* bind the socket to the given port */
memset(&sAddr, 0, sizeof(sAddr));
sAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
sAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(item->szIP);
sAddr.sin_port = htons(ulPort);
if(bind(sRet, (struct sockaddr *)&sAddr, sizeof(sAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    int iTmp = WSAGetLastError();
    closesocket(sRet);
    return(INVALID_SOCKET);
}

cSockParam = 4;
if (setsockopt(sRet, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_TTL, &cSockParam, sizeof(cSockParam)) == -1) {
    int iTmp = WSAGetLastError();
    return (INVALID_SOCKET);
}

/* Construct an IGMP join request structure */
mc_req.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(ccAddress);
mc_req.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr(item->szIP);

/* Send an ADD_MEMBERSHIP message via setsockopt */
if((setsockopt(sRet, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char FAR *) &mc_req, sizeof(mc_req))) == -1) {
    int iTmp = WSAGetLastError();
    return (INVALID_SOCKET);
}

/* Return the created socket. */
return(sRet);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert with sockets but if you look at this [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it says that SO_REUSEADDR should be used with level = SOL_SOCKET parameter. So probably you call should be something like

```
setsockopt(sRet, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,&cSockParam, sizeof(cSockParam))
```

Please try this and let meknow if it made any difference

Comment: That's it! Unbelievable! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure if this is your problem, but the WDS may be using [SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740621.aspx) which is preventing your bind().  The docs in this link would seem to describe the behavior you are reporting.